# JFROG unable to access showing 8046 connection refused

Tags: jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray, jfrog-container-registry, jfrog-mission-control

Recent times jfrog server got rebooted from there when we start jfrog we are getting below stating like 8046 refused.

ERROR:

> Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Answer (score 1):

The problem the access.war file, the folder which was created out of access.war is empty so that created such an issue. Later after deleting the folder and started the service, jfrog came up and running

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be an issue with the port availability.
By meaning **reboot**, are you referring to the VM reboot [or] it's just the Application restart? If it's a VM reboot, we might need to review the port configuration (firewall configuration - whether the [required ports](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements#SystemRequirements-RequirementsMatrix) are available, security groups - if any external provider is being used).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @yuvarajan
firewall status is switched off, done VM and applications reboots both.
ERROR LOG-Artifactory-service.log
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Cluster join: Service registry ping failed; Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Please help me out from this

Comment: 2022-09-12T07:29:28.832Z [jfrou] [FATAL] [735858fd40b2750d] [e_tenant_services_holder.go:35] [main                ] [] - Failed joining Access: cluster join: Service registry ping failed; context deadline exceeded. last error: could not parse error from service registry, status code: 404,
Please verify bot the logs and share your suggestions @yuvarajan

Comment: Are there any specific errors returned in the access-service.log?